# Always present locked screen notification?

Tags: ios

I want my app to be quickly accessible between pre-set hours, say 9am to 5am Mon-Fri from the locked screen so swiping right on the notification will take you directly to the app. Is there a way of making this notification "shortcut" always present on the locked screen during those pre-specified times?

Or if not, is there a way around it? e.g. make the notification pop-up 1 minute after the person locks their screen everytime?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot detect that the screen has been locked. You have local notifications. That's your lot.

Comment: You know with the passbook you can have it so one of the passes always stays up on the locked screen for quick access. Is there anyway of doing the same with an app?